# ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text change based on Checked?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I've added a

ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sales Tax Exempt" Click="btnTaxExempt_Click"

and instead of the check mark when on and the no check mark when off, I want to change the Text to read "Tax Exempt On" or "Tax Exempt Off".  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could update the [ToggleMenuFlyoutItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299158.aspx) to hide the  `CheckGlyph` FontIcon to `Collapsed` and update the text code behind as you want. For example:

XAML

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleMenuFlyoutItemStyle1" TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">   
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleMenuFlyoutItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                         ...
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="AnimationRoot">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="{ThemeResource ToggleMenuFlyoutItemCheckGlyphForeground}" FontSize="16" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE001;" Margin="0,0,12,0" Opacity="0" Width="16"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextTrimming="Clip" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

 <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sales Tax Exempt" Click="btnTaxExempt_Click" Style="{StaticResource ToggleMenuFlyoutItemStyle1}" ></ToggleMenuFlyoutItem>
```

Code behind:

```
private void btnTaxExempt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleMenuFlyoutItem current = sender as ToggleMenuFlyoutItem;
    if(current.IsChecked)
    {
        current.Text = "Tax Exempt On";
    }
    else if(!current.IsChecked)
    {
        current.Text = "Tax Exempt Off";
    }
}
```

The [`ToggleMenuFlyoutItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.togglemenuflyoutitem) should be used inside [`MenuFlyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout), if you are not use a `MenuFlyout`, you may consider to use [`ToggleSwitch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/toggles) instead. `ToggleSwitch` is easy to set [`OnContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ToggleSwitch_OnContent) and [`OffContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ToggleSwitch_OffContent) .